# Call dictionary element from a tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

This is the tuple I have:

```
a = (-2.1900105430326064, 0.20989101040060731, 0, 2106,
 {'1%': -3.4334588739173006,
  '10%': -2.5675011176676956,
  '5%': -2.8629133710702983},
 15436.871010333041)
```

I want to call the "1%" value, and I know from calling dictionary elements it is done by this:

```
a['1%']

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

So I tried calling the element:

```
 a[[3]'1%']
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But that does not seem to be working here.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is `a[4]["1%"]`, the dict it the fifth element with indexes starting at `0`, so `a[4]` gets the fifth element i.e the dict, you then access the key with `["1%"]`:

```
a = (-2.1900105430326064, 0.20989101040060731, 0, 2106,
 {'1%': -3.4334588739173006,
  '10%': -2.5675011176676956,
  '5%': -2.8629133710702983},
 15436.871010333041)
print(a[4]["1%"])
-3.4334588739173006
```

Or access from the end where it is the second last element `-2`:

```
print(a[-2]["1%"])
-3.4334588739173006
```